# High CPU usage in Magento Enterprise 1.12

Tags: magento

We are experiencing very high CPU usage in magento. The Process are listed as php. If a single user visit the website homepage CPU spikes to 30-40%. We tried fresh magento installation with nothing in the database but it still does the same.

We have PHP 5 with PHP 5 Handler Suphp. We are on dedicated server with remote mysql.

Is it normal?

Steve

Edited

I have now switched to Nginx and noticed that the website is super fast and the CPU usage is down to 1/4 of what it used to be with Apache. 
Now working to install Varnish for even better speed. My recommendation for everyone out there is to move to Nginx without wasting time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento can be very intensive, it would depend on the specs of your server on how much strain you would get as a percentage.

Once you enable caching, and add in something like APC / EAccelerator it should drop a bit though.

A Good solution would be to scrap SuPHP and Apache and use Nginx as your webserver, this will greatly reduce the memory footprint and CPU load on your server.

Alternatively you can look into adding Varnish or Squid caching proxies which would also reduce CPU load by quite a bit.

Comment: I am using Enterprise version which already has FPC. Do you think I should go for Varnish? I am also using memcache. Let me know if I should switch to APC.

Comment: You should defiitely be using some sort of opcode caching, such as APC/EAccelerator - although APC could well be enabled by default you would have to look into this.
I often optimize Magento setups and the biggest gains I get are usually from using either a reverse proxy to apache (nginx or varnish or squid) or replacing apache altogether and going to Nginx + FPM.
Apache with suPHP is just far too slow for this kind of setup, it's usually setup like this on CPanel servers by default.

Comment: I have installed mod_deflate and eAccelerator. Is there any configuration changes I have to make for eAccelerator or it works automatically? The performance has improved. However upon further research I have found that Nginx is the answer to the problem we are having so we will definitely go for this.

Comment: Eaccelerator will work automatically and will give you decent gains. As I said above Nginx will get you the biggest gains by a mile ;-)
it can be a pain to setup if you are new to it, but there's a load of help easily found on google. Good luck